# Proving soundness of sequent calculus rules

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

> Prove the soundness of the following rules of the sequent calculus $LK$ for classical logic: $$\dfrac{\Gamma, A(y) \vdash \Delta}{\Gamma,\exists x A(x) \vdash \Delta}{\exists\mathsf I}$$ $$\dfrac{\Gamma \vdash A(t), \Delta}{\Gamma \vdash \exists x A(x), \Delta}{\exists\mathsf r}$$
>
> (where in $(\exists l) \space y$ is an eigenvariable, i.e. $y \notin \Gamma \cup \Delta$).
>
> Are these rules also invertible?

I know how to proof soundness of $(\forall r)$, where I can say something like this:

Assume $\Gamma \models P_1[y/x], \Delta$. Let $(\mathcal{A}, \xi^{\mathcal{A}})$ such that $(\mathcal{A}, \xi^{\mathcal{A}}) \models \Gamma, (\mathcal{A}, \xi^{\mathcal{A}}) \not\models \Delta$ and $(\mathcal{A}, \xi^{\mathcal{A}}) \models P_1[^y /_x]$. Since $y \notin \Gamma, (\mathcal{A}, \xi^{\mathcal{A}}) \models \Gamma$ if and only if $\forall b \in D_{\mathcal{A}} \space (\mathcal{A}, \xi^{\mathcal{A}}[^b/_y]) \models \Gamma$. Hence, $\forall b \in D_{\mathcal{A}} \space (\mathcal{A}, \xi^{\mathcal{A}}) \models \Gamma$ implies $(\mathcal{A}, \xi^{\mathcal{A}}[^b/_y]) \models P_1[^y/_x]$. Hence, $(\mathcal{A}, \xi^{\mathcal{A}}) \models \forall x P_1$, from which $\Gamma \models \forall x P_1, \Delta$ follows.

But, I'm having trouble in converting this proof to $(\exists l)$ and $(\exists r)$. Please note that $(\mathcal{A}, \xi^{\mathcal{A}})$ is an interpretation for a first order language $\mathcal{L}$, where $\mathcal{A}$ is a structure and $\xi^{\mathcal{A}}$ an environment of $\mathcal{A}$. And $D_{\mathcal{A}}$ is the domain.

**EDIT:**

For $(\exists l)$:

Assume $\Gamma, P_1[y/x] \models \Delta$. Let $(\mathcal{A}, \xi^{\mathcal{A}})$ such that $(\mathcal{A}, \xi^{\mathcal{A}}) \models \Gamma, (\mathcal{A}, \xi^{\mathcal{A}}) \not \models \Delta$ and $(\mathcal{A}, \xi^{\mathcal{A}}) \not \models P_1[^y /_x]$. Since $y \notin \Gamma \cup \Delta, (\mathcal{A}, \xi^{\mathcal{A}}) \not \models \Delta$ if and only if $\exists b \in D_{\mathcal{A}} \space (\mathcal{A}, \xi^{\mathcal{A}}[^b/_y]) \not \models \Delta$. Hence, $\exists b \in D_{\mathcal{A}} \space (\mathcal{A}, \xi^{\mathcal{A}}) \not \models \Delta$ implies $(\mathcal{A}, \xi^{\mathcal{A}}[^b/_y]) \not \models P_1[^y/_x]$. Hence, $(\mathcal{A}, \xi^{\mathcal{A}}) \models \exists x P_1$, from which $\Gamma \models P_1[y/x], \Delta$ follows.

For $(\exists r)$:

Assume $\Gamma \models P_1[t/x], \Delta$. Let $(\mathcal{A}, \xi^{\mathcal{A}})$ such that $(\mathcal{A}, \xi^{\mathcal{A}}) \models \Gamma, (\mathcal{A}, \xi^{\mathcal{A}}) \not \models \Delta$ and $(\mathcal{A}, \xi^{\mathcal{A}}) \models P_1[^t /_x]$. Since $(\mathcal{A}, \xi^{\mathcal{A}}) \models \Gamma$ if and only if $\exists b \in D_{\mathcal{A}} \space (\mathcal{A}, \xi^{\mathcal{A}}[^b/_x]) \models \Gamma$. Hence, $\exists b \in D_{\mathcal{A}} \space (\mathcal{A}, \xi^{\mathcal{A}}) \models \Gamma$ implies $(\mathcal{A}, \xi^{\mathcal{A}}[^b/_x]) \models P_1[^t/_x]$. Hence, $(\mathcal{A}, \xi^{\mathcal{A}}) \models \exists x P_1$, from which $\Gamma \models \exists x P_1, \Delta$ follows.

Comment: No; if you consider $\exists$-left : $\Gamma, P_1 \vdash \Delta$,you have to start with $A \vDash \Gamma$, $A \nvDash \Delta$ and $A \nvDash P_1$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I changed it. Was it the only problem in the proof? And how do I decide which ones will be $\not \models$ and which ones $\models$? Is there like a general rule for it?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I also did something for $(\exists r)$, if you have time please check it also.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Is the answer in edit part correct?

Comment: @portal - For $(\exists$-r), it seems to me that the argumetn must involve only $P_1$; i.e. from $A ⊨Γ, A ⊭Δ$ and $A ⊨P_1[b/x]$, you can forget about $\Gamma, \Delta$ (they are unaffected into the bottom seq) and consider that, from $A ⊨P_1[b/x]$ for some $b \in D$, you can conlude with $A ⊨∃xP_1$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I tried to do something following the $(\forall, l)$ rule. And what about $(\exists l)$, is it okay? I changed the beginning as you pointed out. Do you know any book or something where the soundness of these quantifier rules is proved?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA So, last questions, I don't wanna bother you anymore with this problem. In the $(\exists r)$ we can ignore $\Gamma$ and $\Delta$. And is my $(\exists l)$ part correct? And are the rules invertible? I have heard one of the $(\exists)$ rules are invertible, but can't remember which one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hint*

Consider :

> $$\dfrac{\Gamma, A(y) \vdash \Delta}{\Gamma,\exists x A(x) \vdash \Delta}{\exists\mathsf l}$$
>
> with the proviso on the *eigenvariable* $y$ that : $y \notin \Gamma \cup \Delta$.

In order to prove that the rule is *sound*, we have to prove that if the upper sequent is *valid*, so is the lower one, where we say that :

> a sequent $\Gamma \vdash \Delta$ is *valid* if it is satisfied in every
> interpretation, and it is satisfied in the interpretation $\mathfrak F$ **iff**
> either some formula in $\Gamma$ is not satisfied by $\mathfrak F$, or some
> formula in $\Delta$ is satisfied by $\mathfrak F$.

Thus, "discarding" the contexts $\Gamma$ and $\Delta$, we have to show that :

> if $A(y)$ is not satisfied, then also $\exists x A(x)$ is.

Due to the fact that $y \notin \Gamma \cup \Delta$, we have no "limitations" on the choice of the interpretation for $y$; thus, if we cannot find a "suitable" object $b$ in the domain $D$ of the interpretation such that $A[b/y]$ holds in $\mathfrak F$ (i.e. $\mathfrak F \nvDash A[b/y]$), then it is impossible to satisfy $\exists x A(x)$ in $\mathfrak F$ (i.e. also $\mathfrak F \nvDash \exists x A(x)$).

---

Basically, the same argument works for $\exists\mathsf r$, assuming the satisfiability of $A(t)$ in $\mathfrak F$.

Comment: Can you please check my edit, where I tried to give a proof for $(∃l)$ part? I slightly changed your notation, and used the one that we use in the classroom, to be consistent with the proof I provided at the part of $(∀r)$. As long as I got your idea, you say that if we can't find a particular object $b$ that makes our AA true, then we can conclude that $A$ is simply not true. Though, I have a hard time formalize it, like in our example, which the mathematical notations.